# Android HttpPost getting the 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, html, http-post, androidhttpclient

PHP curl request to retrive the data from server getting the response right.

But when i call from Android to `HttpPost` it returns this Error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /service/v2/rest.php
on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.0 (Fedora) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.2.17 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.4.3     
mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.8.8 Server at nl.wooning.cz Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Probably you need to login before you can access the php file...

Comment: When i calls the api from PHP works fine no issue in PHP curl request.
getting the error in HttpPost android calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the permission in .htaccess . Kindly check and provide permissions accordingly. See [this](http://www.techieshelp.com/you-don%E2%80%99t-have-permission-to-access-wp-adminpost-php-on-this-server/) for more information.

Comment: Can you please let me know , which type of permission I have to grant in .htaccess file.
thanks.

Comment: refer this link may help you -http://www.techieshelp.com/you-don%E2%80%99t-have-permission-to-access-wp-adminpost-php-on-this-server/

Answer (score 0):

Did you use  this permission in your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes... It have the internet permission.
This app is working on other server but unfortunately not working on my another server.